# How to map an array of strings from react state to a select box

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I read a json file in the first select box and set the value as state and i don't know how to read that value to another select box. All I get is the whole array as one string.

This is the code where i set state as an object from the first select box:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedCourse: {}
        
    };
    this.onSelectCourse = this.onSelectCourse.bind(this);
}
onSelectCourse(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    this.setState(
        {
            selectedCourse: {
                ...this.state.selectedCourse,
                [e.target.id]: [e.target.value]
            }
        },
        () => {
            console.log(this.state);
        }
    );
}

render() {
    const { selectedCourse } = this.state;
```

This is the first select box:

```
<select onChange={this.onSelectCourse}>{CoursesList.courses.map((item, i) =><option key={i} value={item.dates}>{item.name}</option>)}</select>
```

This is the select box where i want to display the data from state object array:

```
<select>{Object.entries(this.state.selectedCourse).map((item) =><option key={item}>{item}</option>)}</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value]

- [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Meaning each `item` in the `.map` function is an array such as `[key, value]`.

What I think you want to do is,

```
<select>
{Object.entries(this.state.selectedCourse)
  .map(
   ([key, value]) => (<option key={key} value={value}>{value}</option>)
  )
}
</select>
```

If you just want the object values and not the keys, you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or for inverse [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

---

Also, in your `setState` you are accessing `[e.target.id]` but your `<option>` tag has no `id` attribute set.

---

**EDIT**:

As pointed out by OP,

> But in my select box I still get: 2017-05-03,2018-02-01 (as one option)

I think that could be because of the `item.dates` in first select field (`<option key={i} value={item.dates}>{item.name}</option>`). Is the `item.dates` an array ? I recommend you check your JSON.

Comment: I have added an id attribute, just like you mentioned and also changed the code. But in my select box I still get: 2017-05-03,2018-02-01 (as one option), instead of getting listed by order like: option 1->2017-05-03
                      option 2->2018-02-01.

Comment: I think the culprit is the `item.dates` which might be an array. I've updated my answer but if it still doesn't work, please update your question by including the JSON file you are reading.